# What is Exact meaning of Opportunity and LineItem in Salesforce.What is the difference between Opportunity LineItem and Opportunity?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I'm not able to understand what is exactly Opportunity and Line Item in Salesforce.What is the difference between Opportunity and Opportunity Line item ?

Answer (score 14):

**Opportunity** is kind of a pending deal which has an associated $ value with it. It represents that if the Opportunity can be closed successfully, then it will generate the $ amount of revenue for your company.

**OpportunityLineItem** are the Products which are associated to an Opportunity.

A company can have a number of products which it sells. All these products are generalized as Products. However, when a Product, or a number of Products are attached to an Opportunity, then they are called "OpportunityLineItem" records.

The $ value attached to an Opportunity comes from the Products associated with that particular opportunity as each Product (or OpportunityLineItem) has a $ value associated to it.

Please mark it an  an answer if the above explanation was able to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

**Opportunity :** Use the Opportunity object to manage information about a sale or pending deal. Its like new or existing proposal that can turn into business.

**Line item:** : is every line that tells which products are involved in that opportunity

http://www.insightsquared.com/2013/09/why-you-need-product-line-items-in-salesforce/

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitylineitem.htm#i1457294